# React/Redux updating a certain value in an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am just learning redux and this is my first time using it in a project.  I am trying to update a certain value in an array of objects.  The structure of my object is:

```
students: { 
    loading: false, 
    error: null, 
    data: [{
        id: 1, 
        name: "Bob", 
        email: 'whatever@gmail.com', 
        status: 'out'
    }]
}
```

Below are my actions for this and the data it gets back is the id of the student that it needs to update.  These work fine.

```
export const studentCheckInStart = student => ({
    type: "STUDENT_CHECK_IN_START",  
    student
})

export const studentCheckIn = (id) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(studentCheckInStart())
        return axios.put('http://localhost:8080/studentList/'+id)
                .then((response) => {      
                    dispatch(studentCheckInSuccess(response.data))
                }).catch(err => {
                    dispatch(studentCheckInError(err))
                })
    }
}

export const studentCheckInSuccess = (data) => {
    return {
        type: STUDENT_CHECK_IN_SUCCESS, 
        payload: data
    }   
}

export const studentCheckInError = (error) => {
    return {
        type: STUDENT_CHECK_IN_ERROR, 
        error
    }
}
```

Where I'm having the issue is in the reducer

```
case "STUDENT_CHECK_IN_SUCCESS":
    let updatedStudent = state.students.data.findIndex((student) => {
        return student.id === action.payload
    })
    console.log(updatedStudent)
    return { 
        ...state, 
        students: {
            ...state.students[updatedStudent],  
            data: {
                status:'in'
            }
        }
    };
    break;
case "STUDENT_CHECK_IN_START":
    return { 
        ...state,
        students: { 
            ...state.students, 
            loading: true 
        }
    }
    break;
case "STUDENT_CHECK_IN_ERROR":
    return { 
        ...state,
        students: {
            ...state.students, 
            error: action.payload, 
            loading: false
        } 
    }
    break;
```

I'm trying to target the specific student object using the id to find the index of the student I want to target.  Then change just the status of that object to "in".  I know what I have in the `STUDENT_CHECK_IN_SUCCESS` is incorrect, I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: why no spaces anywhere in your code? makes it very hard to read!! welcome to stackoverflow by the way. consider using https://prettier.io/ especially before pasting code examples

Comment: Where is the `id` of student in your object? You are loosing all the other data other then updatedStudent in your students here: `students: {...state.students[updatedStudent],  
  data:{status:'in'} }`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to type it in.  And yes I know what I have is wrong.  But what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Your state seems a little bit complex. Why do you need loading or error in your students object? What other parts do you have in your state beside students? This is one possible way I can think of at this situation (just the related part) :

```
let updatedStudent = state.students.data.findIndex(
    student => student.id === action.payload
);
const newData = [ ...state.students.data ];
newData[ updatedStudent ] = { ...newData[ updatedStudent ], status: "in" }
return { ...state, students: { ...state.students, data: newData } };
```

I will edit my answer if I think a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your action doesn't really need all that payload, just an `id` of the student who checked in. So if you change that, I think you could return this from your reducer action:

```
return {
  ...state,
  students: {
    ...state.students,
    data: state.students.data.map(s => {
      if (s.id === action.id) {
        return { ...s, status: 'in' };
      }

      return s;
    }
  }
};
```

The idea is that you need to return everything unchanged except the data array. By using `map`, we can return a modified version of the data array where the student whose id matches the one supplied in the action will have their status changed to `in`, but the rest of the students in the data array remain unchanged.